# Does the virtual memory of a process ever shrink?

Tags: memory-management

Does the virtual memory of a process ever shrink?. Does the swap size of the process reduce?

Comment: For which operating system are you asking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual memory, today with tons of dirty cheap RAM, is used more for [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection#Paged_virtual_memory) than for swapping on PC.

So there is no 1:1 correlation between used swap and virtual memory.

And with 64bits addresses there is no need for the OS to claim back unused virtual memory pages. It'll do it if it needs to.

If by *swap size*, you mean the swap column in `top`, that's not used swap, but the required swap space to  swap in/out the process.